# Compile my project with SDL2 got Link Error

Tags: c, macos, linker, sdl-2

I have written a small project with SDL2 When I compile on my Macbook Pro, I got link error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_HIDAPI_IsDevicePresent", referenced from:
      _GetDeviceInfo in SDL_sysjoystick.c.o
  "_HIDAPI_UpdateDevices", referenced from:
      _SDL_JoystickUpdate_REAL in SDL_joystick.c.o
  "_METAL_RenderDriver", referenced from:
      _render_drivers in SDL_render.c.o
  "_SDL_HIDAPI_JoystickDriver", referenced from:
      _SDL_joystick_drivers in SDL_joystick.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libs/SDL2/libSDL2-2.0d.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libs/SDL2/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**My system info**

macOS 10.15.4 (19E287)

**My project source code**

https://github.com/yangruihan/libray

Thanks very much! :)

**All build log**

```
--
-- SDL2 was configured with the following options:
--
-- Platform: Darwin-19.4.0
-- 64-bit:   TRUE
-- Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
--
-- Subsystems:
--   Atomic:    ON
--   Audio: ON
--   Video: ON
--   Render:    ON
--   Events:    ON
--   Joystick:  ON
--   Haptic:    ON
--   Power: ON
--   Threads:   ON
--   Timers:    ON
--   File:  ON
--   Loadso:    ON
--   CPUinfo:   ON
--   Filesystem:    ON
--   Dlopen:    ON
--   Sensor:    ON
--
-- Options:
--   3DNOW                  (Wanted: ON): ON
--   ALSA                   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   ALSA_SHARED            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   ALTIVEC                (Wanted: ON): OFF
--   ARMNEON                (Wanted: ON): OFF
--   ARMSIMD                (Wanted: ON): OFF
--   ARTS                   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   ARTS_SHARED            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   ASSEMBLY               (Wanted: ON): ON
--   ASSERTIONS             (Wanted: auto): auto
--   BACKGROUNDING_SIGNAL   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   CLOCK_GETTIME          (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   DIRECTFB_SHARED        (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   DIRECTX                (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   DISKAUDIO              (Wanted: ON): ON
--   DUMMYAUDIO             (Wanted: ON): ON
--   ESD                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   ESD_SHARED             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   FOREGROUNDING_SIGNAL   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   FUSIONSOUND            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   FUSIONSOUND_SHARED     (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   GCC_ATOMICS            (Wanted: ON): ON
--   HIDAPI                 (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   INPUT_TSLIB            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   JACK                   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   JACK_SHARED            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   KMSDRM_SHARED          (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   LIBC                   (Wanted: ON): ON
--   LIBSAMPLERATE          (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   LIBSAMPLERATE_SHARED   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   MMX                    (Wanted: ON): ON
--   NAS                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   NAS_SHARED             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   OSS                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   PTHREADS               (Wanted: ON): ON
--   PTHREADS_SEM           (Wanted: ON): ON
--   PULSEAUDIO             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   PULSEAUDIO_SHARED      (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   RENDER_D3D             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   RENDER_METAL           (Wanted: 0): OFF
--   RPATH                  (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   SDL_DLOPEN             (Wanted: ON): ON
--   SDL_STATIC_PIC         (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   SDL_TEST               (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   SNDIO                  (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   SSE                    (Wanted: ON): ON
--   SSE2                   (Wanted: ON): ON
--   SSE3                   (Wanted: ON): ON
--   SSEMATH                (Wanted: ON): OFF
--   VIDEO_COCOA            (Wanted: ON): ON
--   VIDEO_DIRECTFB         (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_DUMMY            (Wanted: ON): ON
--   VIDEO_KMSDRM           (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_METAL            (Wanted: 0): OFF
--   VIDEO_OFFSCREEN        (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_OPENGL           (Wanted: ON): ON
--   VIDEO_OPENGLES         (Wanted: ON): ON
--   VIDEO_RPI              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_VIVANTE          (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_VULKAN           (Wanted: 0): OFF
--   VIDEO_WAYLAND          (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_WAYLAND_QT_TOUCH (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_X11              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_X11_XCURSOR      (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_X11_XINERAMA     (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_X11_XINPUT       (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_X11_XRANDR       (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_X11_XSCRNSAVER   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_X11_XSHAPE       (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   VIDEO_X11_XVM          (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   WASAPI                 (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   WAYLAND_SHARED         (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--   X11_SHARED             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
--
--  CFLAGS:         -idirafter /Volumes/SSD/Personal/workspace/libray/libs/SDL2/src/video/khronos
--  EXTRA_CFLAGS:  -D_THREAD_SAFE -msse3 -msse2 -msse -m3dnow -mmmx -Wshadow -fvisibility=hidden -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=declaration-after-statement -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall
--  EXTRA_LDFLAGS: -Wl,-undefined,error;-Wl,-compatibility_version,1.0.0;-Wl,-current_version,12.0.0
--  EXTRA_LIBS:    m;iconv;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ForceFeedback.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework
--
--  Build Shared Library: ON
--  Build Static Library: OFF
--
-- If something was not detected, although the libraries
-- were installed, then make sure you have set the
-- CFLAGS and LDFLAGS environment variables correctly.
--
Writing version header for v0.12.0
 Using Apple defaults.
 Using bundled version of GLEW
-- Checking for module 'libstbi'
--   No package 'libstbi' found
 Using bundled version of stb-image
-- Checking for module 'libstbi_write'
--   No package 'libstbi_write' found
 Using bundled version of stb-image-write
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev):
  Policy CMP0068 is not set: RPATH settings on macOS do not affect
  install_name.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0068" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  For compatibility with older versions of CMake, the install_name fields for
  the following targets are still affected by RPATH settings:

   SDL_gpu_shared

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Volumes/SSD/Personal/workspace/libray/build/CMake/Debug
[  1%] Built target SDL2main
[ 16%] Built target Lua
[ 17%] Linking C shared library libSDL2-2.0d.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_HIDAPI_IsDevicePresent", referenced from:
      _GetDeviceInfo in SDL_sysjoystick.c.o
  "_HIDAPI_UpdateDevices", referenced from:
      _SDL_JoystickUpdate_REAL in SDL_joystick.c.o
  "_METAL_RenderDriver", referenced from:
      _render_drivers in SDL_render.c.o
  "_SDL_HIDAPI_JoystickDriver", referenced from:
      _SDL_joystick_drivers in SDL_joystick.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libs/SDL2/libSDL2-2.0d.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libs/SDL2/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```